# ImportError: cannot import name CKParser

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I wrote a class called `CKParser` , in a Flask app
I've been unsuccessful in getting it to load 
**I have:**

```
/myapp
  __init__.py (blank file)
  server.py
  parser.py
```

In my server.py I wrote:

```
from parser import CKParser
```

Later in `server.py` I have:

```
ckparser = CKParser(somdata)
return ckparser.get_ckdata()
```

In my `parser.py` I have:

```
class CKParser(object):
    def __init__(self,ckdata):
        self.ckdata = ckdata
    ...
```

I have some other classes in there too. 
When I try to run the app I get: 
`ImportError: cannot import name CKParser`

I may not fully understand `import` and `from ... import`

I tried importing `from` myapp.parser.
I tried importing just `parser` 
I tried importing just `CKParser` 

I'm out of options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has its own [parser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html) module. I am guessing that may be there is a conflict of names here. Can you rename your parser.py to myparser.py etc. and then call the import as:

### `myparser.py`

```
class CKParser(object)
....whatever
```

### `server.py`

```
from myparser import CKParser
```

Comment: Just to let you know it wasn't `myapp.myparser`
It was just `from myparser import CKParser`
I think because they are in the same directory. Right?

Comment: oh right. you can just do "from myparser..". I edited the answer again.